# Binance Future api : APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip

Tags: python, api, algorithmic-trading, binance

I used Binance Python api in my algotrading bot, but I get an error when I use future market api.
'''
BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip
'''
I am sure that my API-key is true and I enabled Future api permissions in setting.
I get this error only when I used that for future market. It was perfectly work for spot Market.
what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

In my code, I have a "client" variable:

```
client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='us')
```

and, here's the thing:

if you are using a non-US version of Binance, and you have not registered your account on the US website, then remove  tld='us'

And vice-versa!

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that one out. The tld='us' seemed optional at first until you pointed out the Binance.US difference. This fixed my issues

Answer (score 6):

Before creating your API key you must open a Futures Account. Then go and create the API key. Then tap the "Edit Restrictions" button and check the option "Enable Futures". After you do it you will see this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Binance Futures has both a testing environment, and a live environment.

By default, the Python SDK you're using connects to the Testnet. You can see this behaviour in the [constant/system.py](https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python/blob/master/binance_f/constant/system.py) file.

You can either:

- modify the system.py file to use Live urls by default instead
- or specify it into your instance of RequestClient directly. RequestClient(api_key=xxx, secret_key=xxx, url='https://fapi.binance.com')

Related issue: https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have use this ....
`client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, tld='us')`
then change as per your account such as,
binance.com, then use **tld='com'**.
binance.us, then use **tld ='us'**.

And also change the restriction and **enable Spot & Margin trading**.