# BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action

Tags: python, api-key, binance-api-client

I have a similar issue to this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870237/binance-future-api-apierrorcode-2015-invalid-api-key-ip-or-permissions-f/70349913#7034991)

[image]

I tried [Artur's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300349/7768490) but it did not work.

Also, I tried [matagus solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511597/7768490) when I created API, the `Enable Future` grey out and can not modify.

Using `Google Colab- Non-US (Canada)- Windows 10`

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's good to define what exactly is the issue now... This problem can have 3 different issues, your keys, ip-block or other permissions.

I had this once before. At that time I used some test-keys. When I changed them back to my live keys, but used the TEST urls it worked again.

Hope this can help you out a little ?