# Python Binance API binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action

Tags: python, binance

My Code is simple as:

```
from binance import Client

api_key = api_key
api_secret = api_secret

def main():
    client = Client(api_key, api_secret, testnet=True)

    info = client.get_account()
    print(info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

error:

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.
```

I am sure api_key and api_secret is right, and I am trying to use it on binance futures testnet. I already read all other questions, none of them worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binance Future api : APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870237/binance-future-api-apierrorcode-2015-invalid-api-key-ip-or-permissions-f)

Answer (score -1):

The futures testnet has its own api key, individually from Binance.

Sign up at https://testnet.binancefuture.com/
In the menu where you select "Positions, Open Orders, etc" you will find "Api Key". Use that one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYlxo.jpg)